# How to set data bar of type duration based on the adjacent cells in excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am new to excel, I just wanted to know how to set the **data bar** based on the **adjacent cells**.

When I tried to do so, It said *multiple cells are not allowed* or *relative cells not allowed in conditional formatting*

I managed to do so by setting the data bar one by one. But I just wonder if there was any simple way to apply that to large chunk of data.

Please refer the image below.

[image]

In this image all the cells in the COMPLETED row is referring to the first element of the TODO, that is 8:00:00 . I want that to set to its own adjacent cells.

Comment: Simply select all cells--> Conditional Formatting-->Data Bars.

Comment: I just tried the same thing and I also got the error message that only absolute cell references are allowed in data bar conditional formatting, it was a surprise to me too. I can only advise you to configure conditional formatting on one particular cell, using an absolute reference, record this in a macro and adapt the macro to your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you'll get a macro, containing this (more or less):

```
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
        .MinPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueAutomaticMin
        .MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueNumber, newvalue:= _
        "=$C$7"
    End With
```

You might change this into:

```
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
        .MinPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueAutomaticMin
        .MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueNumber, newvalue:= _
        "=$C$" + ActiveCell.Row
    End With
```

(something like that)